# JSF commandButton issue

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am providing a search function using JSF. I get the list and display it correctly in a datatable :

```
<p:dataTable id="props" var="prop" value="#{propController.propSearch}" editable="true" style="margin-bottom:20px">
    <p:column headerText="Id" width="20">                                       
        <h:outputText value="#{prop.id}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Name" width="300">                  
        <h:outputText value="#{prop.name}"/>                                                               
     </p:column>  
     <p:column headerText="Description">
         <h:outputText value="#{prop.shortDescription}" />                 
     </p:column>  
     <p:column headerText="Price" width="120">               
         <h:outputText value="#{prop.price}" />
     </p:column>  
     <p:column width="120">                 
         <h:commandButton value="View Prop" immediate="true" action="#{propController.viewSingleProp(prop)}" />                 
     </p:column>
     <p:column width="120">                 
         <h:commandButton value="Delete" immediate="true" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this prop?')" actionListener="#{propController.deleteProp(prop)}" />                                    
     </p:column> 

</p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

However the commandButton to view each individual item does not get called. Instead the search page just refreshes with no data.

Why is this happening?

Comment: How does the method `viewSingleProp(prop)` look like ?

Answer (score 0):

(I hope your opening tag of  `<h:form>` is just missing in your code posted in your question, not in your actual code!)

You need to remove the attribute `immediate="true"` from the `h:commandButton`.

See:

- [Immediate=true VS immediate=false in JSF Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196208/immediate-true-vs-immediate-false-in-jsf-component)

Comment: Thanks for your response. removing immediate=true has no effect :(

Comment: If you use a `p:commandButton` instead of an `h:commandButton`? This should have the ajax functionality

Comment: I give up. Going back to struts 2. More user friendly I think.

Comment: Don't give up. Show us the code for `PropController` (should you have posted in the first place btw.)